# How do I get at this piece of info in a nested array/object?

Tags: php, arrays

`print_r($rows)` returns this:

```
Array
(
    [S1 | Excellence in P-O-P Execution: Ripping Down the Roadblocks to Breakthrough In-Store Marketing] => Array
        (
            [group] => S1 | Excellence in P-O-P Execution: Ripping Down the Roadblocks to Breakthrough In-Store Marketing
            [rows] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [nid] => 207
                            [node_title] => Excellence in P-O-P Execution: Ripping Down the Roadblocks to Breakthrough In-Store Marketing
                            [taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_track_term_tid] => 19
                            [node_field_data_field_speaker_title] => Jon Kramer
                            [node_field_data_field_speaker_nid] => 205
                            [field_data_field_date_time_field_date_time_value] => 2012-10-16 18:00:00
                            [field_data_field_session_number_field_session_number_value] => S1
                            [field_data_field_date_time_node_entity_type] => node
                            [field_data_field_session_number_node_entity_type] => node
                            [field_data_field_track_icon_taxonomy_term_entity_type] => taxonomy_term
                            [field_data_field_job_title_node_entity_type] => node
                            [field_data_field_company_node_entity_type] => node
                            [field_data_field_hide_track_node_entity_type] => node
```

(I know I'm missing all the closing parens; the return is actually several thousand lines long and I'm just too lazy to go through and find all of them.)

How would I go about getting at the piece of data called nid? I had thought it would be

```
$rows[0]['rows'][0]->nid
```

but I get an undefined offset error. I absolutely cannot access the first level of the array using the full contents (S1 | Excellence etc.) - this is dynamically generated. I had thought since it's the first element  of the array I could get at it with the zero offset, but apparently not.

**Updated**

I've tried a few things using `current()` as per the answer below; it gets me one level closer but I still cannot access the nid element.

```
$row = current($rows);
$nid_tmp = $row['rows'];
print '<pre>'; var_dump($nid_tmp); print '</pre>';
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 207
```

Fine; that's what I was expecting. But when I try `print $nid_tmp[0]->nid`, I get "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't started looping through the array, you can use current() to get the first element. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

```
$row = current($rows); // returns the first element of the array
$firstObject = $row['rows'][0];
$nid = $firstObject->nid;
```

Or you can use reset() to rewind the pointer AND get the first element.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

```
$row = reset($rows);
```

You can also use array_shift() to get the first element of an array, but it will REMOVE that element from the array when you do so.

None of these functions care about the key type.

Comment: So then how do I get to the elements? I'm assuming I can't do something like `current($rows)[0]->nid`; do I have to set the result of `current($rows)` to another variable and then go from there?

Comment: I'm completely stuck from here. I'm updating the OP to show what I've tried so far and the results it's given.

Comment: I've added to my answer. I think you missed a level in your first comment. Maybe. Whoever made that array is not your friend. :)

Comment: You're right; I missed that extra level of rows. It's dynamically generated by a Drupal view that's grouped by multiple fields. When I try the new version you posted, I get "Notice: Undefined offset: 0". I also tried a different way and got a different error (updated OP a few minutes ago with that.) I'm stumped.